# overflow:hidden Parent div not expanding to floated children

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am making a megadropdown menu and have this structure

```
<li>
    <div class="drop_div4">  
          <div class="child">  <----floated child
          <div class="child">  <----floated child
          <div class="child">  <----floated child
```

the problem is that depending on access rights i will have to hide any of the child divs and so i want the **drop_div4** to be able expand automatically but currently if i remove the width on it then all child divs are shown below one another.

I have tried adding `overflow:hidden,float:left` to the **drop_div4** div but it doesnt work

Adding `min-width` and hoping it would grow also doesnt help.

Adding `<div style="clear:both">` as the last div also doesnt help

I have set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pankajsingh5k/H6Tgu/) for the same with the width removed on the parent div and all the child div are showing below one another.

To see how it looks when all the child div are visible please uncomment the width:550px in the **.drop_div4** class

Kindly help as i have no clue as to why this is happening.

Comment: So just to be clear, you would like the child elements to appear side by side in the drop-down menu as they do when the width is un-commented so that when elements are added the menu grows in width and adds the child div horizontally rather than vertically?